# Encrypt/Decrypt Connection Strings

Tags: sql, encryption, connection-string

There is lots of information on encrypting and decrypting connection strings available.  However, we need help on which method to use for our situation.  We have many tablet clients connecting to an Azure database.  We need to protect the username and password in the connection string on all of the clients.  We don't want to have to create a key for each client but rather have one key for all of them. Better yet, no key at all.  What is the simplest approach to use?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the threat that you're trying to counter?

Comment: I thought it would be obvious.  Access to our Azure database.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "*access*". By whom? To do what? If you want to prevent well-resourced, motivated technicians (who own both the device and the network over which it is connecting) from discovering connection parameters, then you may as well give up now. As @MichaelTeper suggests, introducing an intermediate tier enables you to restrict direct database access to that tier; but whilst the tier can introduce more application-specific restrictions on user activity than could (easily) be implemented within the database itself, issues of keeping secret any authentication credentials remain.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to be able to decrypt the connection string, you would need to distribute a certificate to your tablets along with your application, and depending on the target OS that may be cumbersome or outright impossible.

My suggestion would be to put a middle tier between your clients and your database. It could be as thin as you need (e.g. look at OData), but would effectively protect your access to the DB.

Alternatively, set up a properly restricted user, and distribute the connection string in clear text.

Comment: We can add a key or key pair to our installation package without any trouble.  We want to avoid needing a unique key or key pair for each tablet.